# Google Cloud Build Trigger Doesn't Work Properly

Tags: triggers, google-cloud-build

I will start off by describing the architecture of my code. I've written code in a directory that's responsible for creating a Cloud Run container. I created a Cloud build trigger that detects a push to the project, and uses a cloudbuild.yaml file to build the Cloud Run container and deploy the code. However, when I push my changes, nothing happens: there are no messages in the history tab showing an error or status message. I've double checked to make sure the directory and file names were put in correctly to the trigger.

Here are the contents of my yaml file:

```yaml
steps:
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    args: ['build', '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/combined', '.']
    id: 'building dockerfile'
    dir: 'name_of_directory'
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    args: ['push', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/combined']
    id: 'pushing the new image'
    dir: 'name_of_directory'
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
    args: ['run', 'deploy', 'name_of_directory', '--image=gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/combined', '--platform=managed', '--region=us-central1', '--memory=4096M', '--service-account=cloud-run-pubsub-invoker@$PROJECT_ID.iam.gserviceaccount.com']
    id: 'deploying combined service'
    dir: 'name_of_directory'
```

The pipeline is fired up if a commit is made to the branch. In the 'included files' input, I have added the main file in the directory to be run. I have also included the .yaml file. Here is a screenshot of the trigger. I can't show too much info, as it's not a personal repo.

[Screenshot of Google Cloud Build trigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4dvV.jpg)

I tried running the trigger manually on the triggers page, and got this error: `Failed to trigger build`. This doesn't help me much, because it's not specific enough.

Has this been encountered before? Or are there any common mistakes that I could check for?

Comment: Please edit your original question and add the cloudbuild yaml and the Cloud Build trigger configured.

Comment: I have added the cloudbuild yaml contents. What do you mean by the Cloud Build trigger configured?

Comment: How your pipeline is triggered? Commit to a branch? Please attach to the original post how you've set up

Comment: you can run the following command and provide the information that asked CaioT, ```$ gcloud beta builds triggers describe YOUR_TRIGGER```, please try to erase/replace any private information like the project ID or anything

Comment: I have added more details underneath the .yaml file contents. Is there more information I need to add?

Comment: Can you upload a screenshot of the trigger settings?

Comment: I added a screenshot, as well as some additional information

Answer (score 2):

I have solved it (or rather, I showed it to someone else who solved it). It turned out I named my directory wrong - it was off by one letter. The build was failing because it couldn't find the directory that the trigger was pointing to! I suppose the lesson is to carefully check that your directory names and other parameters match between the project repository and trigger settings.